# Python: Define list within a class

Tags: list, class, python-3.5

I can't find the answer, so I decided to post this question:

I am rewriting my code to make it Object Orientated, and I am having some difficulty:

```
class Validation():
    def __init__(self, input=path_property, output=validation_output):
        self.input = input
        self.outpu = output
        self.groupList = []
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Input: %s\nOutput: %s\nGroup List: %s' % (self.input, self.outpu, self.groupList)

    def csvExtract(self, d, groupList, n):
        with open(self.input, 'r') as csv_input:
            reader = csv.reader(csv_input, delimiter=',')
            for d in reader:
                self.groupList.append(d[n])
        self.groupList.pop(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    validate = Validation()
    validate.csvExtract('col', groupList, 3)
    print(groupList)
    print(validate)
```

This code simply reads a .csv file, and adds elements of the third column to a list. This worked fine when it wasn't put into a class, and a list was defined at the start of the code.

Now I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/validation.py", line 34, in <module>
    validate.csvExtract('col', groupList, 3)
NameError: name 'groupList' is not defined
```

I'm also planning to make arguments of `csvExtract()` (`d` - indicates column, and `n` - indicates number of columns) a part of 
`__init__()`.

I have tried few different approaches, could you help me with that?

Comment: You don't need to pass `groupList` as an argument. Change the function signature to `def csvExtract(self, d, n):` and use `print (validate.groupList)`

Comment: Wow, that was quick. In the same manner, i defined `d` as dimension and remove it from `csvExtract`, so only `n` has left - but i can't define it in the `__init__` - no idea why.